# Stored Procedure Delete Microsoft SQL Server Management

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

In Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, I have to create a stored procedure to delete a customer and foreign key records associated with this customer, but I can not use cascade, I must explicitly delete the records using delete statements.

I am new to queries/databases and I am not sure if what I have done is the correct way or maybe it's even cascade what I am using. Would be great if someone could give me their thoughts.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uspDeleteCust1;
    @CustomerId1 INT;
AS;
BEGIN;
    DELETE FROM Accounts1 WHERE CustomerId1 = @CustomerId1;
    DELETE FROM Associations1 WHERE CustomerAId1 = @CustomerId1;
    DELETE FROM Associations1 WHERE CustomerBId1 = @CustomerId1;
    DELETE FROM Customers1 WHERE CustomerId1 = @CustomerId1;
END;
```

EXECUTE uspDeleteCust1;
    2; --(Id)

Comment: Please show us what you have so far, so that we can best assist you. It is also helpful to specific the database system used.

Comment: Just added there, thank you @TheLyrist

Comment: You probably would want to create a transaction for all your statements so that the entire operation can be rolled back if any of your statements causes any error. Not knowing your database platform it is impossible to provide exact example, but the idea is pretty much the same. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your approach is pretty much perfect.

I'd second wrapping everything in a Transaction as you don't want a partial delete.

One Thing to watch for is that you might find that there are other tables dependent on some of your deleted tables. These may not have a CustID column.
So you'll need to delete via a Sub query-

EG (I made up this table but you get the idea)

```
DELETE FROM account1_transaction Where AccountId IN 
(Select accountid from Account1 WHERE customerId = @CustomerId)
```

Finally - I'd make use of TRY.. CATCH as it makes it a lot easier to decide whether to COMMIT or ROLLBACK the Transaction

EG

```
    BEGIN TRY

    BEGIN TRANSACTION

        DELETE FROM Accounts1 WHERE CustomerId1 = @CustomerId1;
        DELETE FROM Associations1 WHERE CustomerAId1 = @CustomerId1;
        DELETE FROM Associations1 WHERE CustomerBId1 = @CustomerId1;
        DELETE FROM Customers1 WHERE CustomerId1 = @CustomerId1;

    COMMIT
    END TRY

BEGIN CATCH

ROLLBACK

END CATCH
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you input! Helped me a lot!